# How to initialize to zero/NULL in a template

Tags: c++, variable-initialization

While writing a template, I want to initialize my variable to a value that serves as zero or null the the data type. If I set it to 0x00 is it going to serve as zero/NULL for any type ?

for example

This is template declaration

```
template <class T>
...
T A=0x00;
```

Now if I define an instance of type T => std::string the above statement serves as `NULL` ?

What about "`int`" and "`unsigned int`". For both of the it serves as "0" ?

Comment: `T`'s default constructor will take care of this for you.

Comment: Unless `T` does not have a default constructor, that is.  `T A;` will initialize `A` if `T` is a class type with a default constructor, but will not initialize `A` at all if `T` is an integer type, for instance.

Comment: You're of course assuming that the type `T` has some kind of zero. This is generally only the case for numerical types. What would be the zero for `class Color` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [Value Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

```
T A = T(); // before C++11

T A{}; // C++11 and later
```

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 1) if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called;
>   (until C++11)
>
> 1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>   (since C++11)
>
> 2) if T is an non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   (until C++11)
>
> 2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;
>   (since C++11)
>
> 3) if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
>
> 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 8):

You may use

```
T t{};
```

for [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: Note that this brace syntax for value initialization is C++11 only.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: and your requires an accessible copy constructor :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau [Doesn't it?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25fbc8eec3622322) Even if the compiler performs copy elision, I still believe the copy ctor should be accessible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Although item 1) of your answer seem to say otherwise... I tried compiling with `-std=c++98` also, and the code still doesn't compile (making the copy ctor `private` instead of `delete`d). I wonder whether cppreference is right here.

Comment: [Follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602933/do-we-need-an-accessible-copy-constructor-for-value-initialization-in-c98)