# Do we need an accessible copy constructor for value initialization in C++98/03?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, value-initialization

**This question refers only to pre C++11**. Consider the following seemingly broken code:

```
struct X
{
    X(){} // default user-provided constructor
private:
    X(const X&){}
};

int main()
{
    X x = X();
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/defb838ffe76e80b)

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) in pre C++11 the default ctor will be called:

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 1) if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the default constructor is called;
>
> ...

This seem to imply that the copy ctor doesn't necessarily need to be accessible. Is this correct or not? The code above does not compile, so it seems that a copy ctor **must** be accessible.

Comment: Apparently I misread cppreference.com in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34602774/65863). #1 you quote above refers to the `X()` proportion of the `X x = X();` expression. That is default-constructing a temp object. The `x = ...` portion then copy-constructs `x` using the temp object as input.

Comment: C++98 doesn't have a notion of "value initialization". That was added in C++03.

Comment: @KerrekSB So basically there is no way to "trick" the compiler in simulating `X x{};` in C++98/03. In other words, the code above compiles in C++11 if we do `X x{};`, and it seems there is no way to achieve the same effect with C++98/03. Of course `X x();` won't do it, as [we all know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @vsoftco: Well, if it's so important, you can write a wrapper: `template <typename T> struct VI { VI() : t() {} T t; };`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value initialization doesn't require it, but you need an accessible copy constructor to do this:

```
X x = X();
```

That's copy initialization, which requires an accessible copy constructor. Even though it will not call that copy constructor, it still needs to exist.

C++17 might be the first version where that need will be lifted.

Comment: Ohh ok, yes, value initialization is done on the temporary. And yes, for copy initialization, we need an accessible copy ctor, even if copy elision is performed.